# Error with ruby bundle install

Tags: ruby, ruby-c-extension

When I try to running bundle install I see:

```
To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can
be found here:

C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86-
mingw32/2.3.0/nio4r-2.1.0/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/nio4r-2.1.0 for 
inspection.
Results logged to
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86-
mingw32/2.3.0/nio4r-2.1.0/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing nio4r (2.1.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install nio4r -v '2.1.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I am using Windows 10, Ruby 2.3.3, Rails 5.0.2.

`mkmf.log` content is:

```
"gcc -o conftest.exe -IC:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/include/ruby-2.3.0/i386-
mingw32 -IC:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/backward -
IC:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/include/ruby-2.3.0 -I. -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -
D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -
O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-
parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -
Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-
statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-
packed-bitfield-compat conftest.c  -L. -LC:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib -L.      
-lmsvcrt-ruby230  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
```

Checked program was:

```
#include "ruby.h"

#include <winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Running `gem install nio4r -v '2.1.0'` also shows an error?

Comment: It'd be helpful for us to help you if provide as much info as possible while posting the question, what is the content of your mkmf.log file, which should give some info on the error

Comment: Yes, I am running gem install nio4r -v '2.1.0' and same error show me

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide the contents of `mkmf.log`, located in `C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86-
mingw32/2.3.0/nio4r-2.1.0/`

Answer (score 1):

If other gems have same error (and it's initial `bundle install`), try to change in gemfile `source 'https://rubygems.org'` to `source 'http://rubygems.org'`.

I had this problem on windows in corporate network, and problem somewhere with ssl. That solution works for me, but i know, it isn't best solution.

But it's a bad recommendation, if any other gem installed with success.

Comment: I already try, changed it to  source 'http://rubygems.org'  not working

Comment: I mean changed it to http